# Updating angular version

Tags: bower

I want to update my angular version from 1.4.9 to 1.5.6. While executing **bower install angular#1.5.6 --save** I am getting ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular.

Here is the trace:

```
$ bower install angular#1.5.6 --save
bower angular#1.5.6             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#1.5.6           validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#1.4.8             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular#1.4.8           validate 1.4.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower angular#>=1.3.0           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#>=1.3.0         validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.0
bower angular#1.4.10            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.10
bower angular#1.4.10          validate 1.4.10 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.10
bower angular#1.5.5             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.5
bower angular#1.5.5           validate 1.5.5 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.5
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <1.6     cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#>=1.2.26 <1.6   validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2.26 <1.6
bower angular#*                 cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#*               validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower angular#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0         validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0
bower angular#~1.x                              cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#~1.x                            validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.x
bower angular#~1.3.13                           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.20
bower angular#~1.3.13                         validate 1.3.20 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.13
bower angular#>1.2.0                            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#>1.2.0                          validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>1.2.0
bower angular#>=1.3.x                           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.6
bower angular#>=1.3.x                         validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.3.x
bower                                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

my bower file is:

```
{
  "name": "myAppName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.9",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-bootstrap": " 0.13.4",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.8",
    "angular-datatables": "~0.5.1",
    "angular-filter": "~0.5.8",
    "angular-material": "~0.11.4",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.9",
    "angular-translate": "^2.9.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.8.1",
    "angular-ui-date": "~0.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "datatables": "~1.10.10",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "md-chips": "~0.2.4",
    "ngprogress": "^1.1.2",
    "textAngular": "~1.4.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "moment": "^2.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.9",
    "textAngular": "~1.4.6",
    "md-chips": "~0.2.4"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "myModuleName",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.9",
    "angular": "1.4.9",
    "angular-translate": "^2.9.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "jquery": {
      "main": "dist/jquery.js"
    },
    "md-chips": "~0.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this  bower install angular#1.5.6 --save --force

Comment: possibly duplicate of    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373484/how-to-update-the-version-of-angular-in-ionic-framework

Answer (score 9):

> bower install angular#latest --save -F

-F = --force-latest: Force latest version on conflict

Answer (score 1):

`bower install` will install the latest **stable** version of angular.