# How to update to angular 1.5

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-1.5, ionic-material

I am working with the code from below link http://ionicmaterial.com/ and wan to work with angular 1.5. I have checked the package.json and they have not specified any angular dependency.So don't know where and how to update to angular 1.5. I have referred the following to [How to update the version of Angular in Ionic Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373484/how-to-update-the-version-of-angular-in-ionic-framework). But I dont want my ionic to crack.